# Reorganized local Picture subfolders but changes not showing in Onedrive

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

I'm synced my Picture folder with Onedrive last week but today I reorganized my local 'Pictures' Folders. The changes are not reflecting in Onedrive even after I click 'Sync' the folder in Onedrive.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should try updating your Windows (Windows update) or get Windows 8.1 from the store

> *ms-windows-store:WindowsUpgrade*

with the link in gray.
Also, check sync settings again. Check OneDrive and your device.

Comment: I have 8.1 but I will try updating windows again.